# sublime text which plugin is overriding key binding

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to use a certain key binding ctrl+alt+j to find a matching pair using emmet.

when I access it from the menu it works perfectly but when I try to use the key binding I get the output of another plugin.

what's the best way to see what plugin has taken over this binding? how can I make emmet retake this binding.

Answer (score 0):

[Keymaps](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Keymaps)

> Plugin for Sublime Text 2/3 editor that enables searching for keymaps by function as well as showing all enabled keymaps in a searchable color-coded list - Cheat Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing was to grep the packages folder
`Preferences --> Browse Packages` for files with the extension

> *.sublime-keymap

that contain the key binding I was looking for.

In my case in was JSHint :)